# Wireframe and prototyping comptability with Oracle ADF user interface components

Tags: interaction-design, information-architecture, wireframe, prototype

I really hope this question does not get closed as its pretty important to me:)

I have recently started a big project in which Oracle ADF is the backend. Having said that, Oracle ADF has it's own restrictive set of UI components, which makes creating interactive prototypes difficult. I normally use Axure for interactive prototypes, but it seems as though these Oracle ADF user interface components are not compatible with Axure. Does anyone have experience creating wireframes or prototypes with Oracle ADF user interface components? Is there any wireframe or prototyping tool that maybe has an extension or some sort of compatibility with Oracle ADF UI components? I know Visio does, but Visio cannot produce interactive prototypes. Any suggestions here?

Comment: I have flagged this question as it's a shopping request.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but a good starting point:  use Oracle's DeFT at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/ux/applications/gps-1601227.html.  You provide use cases and the tool provides design patterns.